# Ubuntu 20.04 will not upgrade to 22.04

Tags: command-line, upgrade, 22.04

I received the prompt to upgrade my Dell Vostro 1720 Laptop from 20.04 to 22.04 but nothing happens when I choose "Yes" to upgrade. I've tried using the terminal to upgrade by running this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

I get this response:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
```

`sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting`

```
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I get the same response when I try to run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

I have tried every thing but keep getting this same response.

Next, I tried installing it from a usb, but when I select to boot from the USB, the screen displays, "GRUB" then goes black to a blinking line cursor. So I am completely unable to bring up any way to install.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You need to boot into a LiveUSB and then go into the filesystem of your hard drive and change the permissions of `etc/sudoers` with `chmod` and `o-w`.  That's the only way to fix that error.  The sudoers file is somehow made world writable and that is not permitted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have 22.04 on a bootable USB but when I select to boot from the USB, the screen displays, "GRUB" then goes black to a blinking line cursor. I'm unable to get to an option to even run the new version from the stick.

Comment: depending on the USB stick's speed it can take a while.  the latest 22.04 boot from a stick I did for my new XPS laptop took a solid 10 minutes to get from the "Try Ubuntu" selection to the actual GUI being interactive.  So it's possible that you need to wait a bit.  The GRUB prompt should show up for your USB stick asking you to install or try ubuntu.  Then you need to wait.  Otherwise, it's trying to boot into your system and not the USB stick.  You might need to modify your boot order in your BIOS/firmware to try booting removable media first.

Comment: I'll try waiting longer... I did burn 22.04 to a DVD & tried to boot to this. The screen went to a blinking cursor for a bit, then went black...then it totally ignored the DVD & booted back into the system. So, at this juncture, I may have to just format the hard drive & start from scratch. It's not loading any form of medium for me to upgrade. I keep getting the notice boxes to upgrade, but when I click to proceed, it does nothing.